# Solve differential equation $u_t = i u_{xx} - x^2 u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider $u_t = i u_{xx} - x^2 u$ with $u_{t = 0} = 1$.

We want to find a solution.

My attempt : let's say $u = X(x)T(t)$, hence we have $\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} = i \frac{X"(x)}{X(x)} - x^2$.

We may say that $\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} = \lambda$ and $i \frac{X"(x)}{X(x)} - x^2 = \lambda$ , so $ \frac{X"(x)}{X(x)} =  -i(x^2 + \lambda)$.

But the second equation is give some problem.

Maybe there is a better way to solve it?

**UPD** : I actually think that this idea is bad, because if $u = X(x)T(t)$, when $u(x,0) = X(x) = 1$

Comment: You've found the final result, but this indeed is the easiest solution for a PDE

Comment: @acarturk maybe there is a simple form?

Comment: i thought about the laplace transform method but i get the same problem, infact the solution of the second equation is the  Parabolic cylinder function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function

Comment: @logo maybe conditions give us something better?

Comment: @openspace Are you sure that the equation is correct? $u_t = i u_{xx} - i x^2 u$ would make much more physical and mathematical sence. In this case you would obtain the equation for X as $X'' + (x^2 + \lambda) X = 0$ as usual ( reemplacing $\lambda$  for $i \lambda$ in your equations as we know it must be imaginary).

Comment: @themaker what about this update?

Comment: @themaker anyway the latter equaiton is hard to solve.